# how to check if a string variable is comma delimited in XSL?

Tags: html, xml, regex, xslt-1.0

I need to test if a xsl variable contains just one word or multiple comma separated words in xslt.

since the variable is dynamic, its a parameter that maps to url querystring which can either be sth like this:

```
index.aspx?role=manager
```

or

```
index.aspx?role=manager,director
```

in XSLT, i need to find out if the $role parameter is  just one word or multiple comma separated words. If multiple words, then i need to extract each word and do xslt filtering based on those words like

```
/rows/row[role=extractedWord[1] or role = extractedWord[2]
```

so that only those rows matching for manager or director roles are returned.

Is this possible?

UPDATE:
I have a filter like this:

`<xsl:variable name="AllPerRole"`   `select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[contains(@EmployeeRoles,$Role)]"  />`

If role has just one value like `index.aspx?role=manager` then above works fine. 
But if role is multiple words like these,
 `index.aspx?role=manager,director`
 then i need to some extract that string 'manager,CEO' and be able to do the following:

`<xsl:variable name="AllPerRole"`   `select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[contains(@EmployeeRoles,$Role{firstRole}) or contains(@EmployeeRoles,$Role{2ndRole})]"  />`

Comment: Which version of XSLT? XSLT 2 has regexes, XSLT 1 does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a variable for the first role in $Role as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="Role1">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($Role, ',')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($Role, ',')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$Role" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

And then set up a variable Role2 for the second role (if any), using `substring-after()` instead of `substring-before()`.

Then:

```
<xsl:variable name="AllPerRole"
    select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[
     contains(@EmployeeRoles,$Role1) or contains(@EmployeeRoles,$Role2)]" />
```

Comment: Thank you, although only problem is there can be as many as 5 or even more comma separated words in the $Role parameter. Can we for-each each words in $Role and save each of them in like $Role[0],$Role[1] etc?

Comment: @SarikaThapaliya: For that you may want to use an XSLT 1.0 implementation of `tokenize()`. This may be available as an extension in your XSLT processor, or there is an XSLT 1.0 implementation available via http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/.